# Generate cab files on Linux

Tags: java, linux, cab

I'm looking for a stanadlone application, script or library (better Java) to generate cab files on Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May I ask which distribution you are using?

If you are using Ubuntu, the package [cabextract](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/cabextract) can read and extract a .cab file while the pacakge [lcab](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/lcab) lets you create one.

You may install the `lcab` package via the `apt-get install` command:

```
sudo apt-get install lcab
```

You may search the packages you want at [Ubuntu Packages Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/).

Please let me know if you are not using Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm looking for something to work both on Ubuntu Server & REH ... Solaris/OpenSolaris will be a dream ... too

Comment: [Here](http://www.cabextract.org.uk/) is the official site of `cabextract`. You may find `.deb` (Debian / Ubuntu), `.rpm` (Redhat / Fedora / CentOS) as well as `.pkg` (Solaris) packages there. Alternatively, you may use the `yum install cabextract` command to install `cabextract` on Radhat too. You may find `lcab` [here](http://freshmeat.net/projects/lcab/). As far as I know, there is no Redhat / Solaris package for it. But since it says it's POSIX compatible, you should be able to compile it as usual.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to [lcab](http://freshmeat.net/projects/lcab/) or [libmspack](http://www.cabextract.org.uk/libmspack/).